# didReceiveMemoryWarning is not called in some view controllers in UINavigationController's view controller stack

Tags: ios, didreceivememorywarning

I made UINavigationViewController with View Controller A as root view controller, and then push view controller B.
When I simulate memory warning in simulator, only A's didReceiveMemoryWarning is called. Surely I've overrided didReceiveMemoryWarning in both A and B.
Eventually I've worked around the problem by calling B's didReceiveMemoryWarning inside A's didReceiveMemoryWarning. However I don't know why B's method is automatically called.
A's viewDidUnload and B's viewDidUnload are both called as expected since I trigger the warning while presenting modal view controller from B.

If view controller B is the root of navigation controller, it's didReceiveMemoryWarning is called with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most common causes I've seen of this are:

- You're calling `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` in one of your view controllers. You shouldn't do this, because `UIViewController` registers for notifications for things like this.
- You're doing something strange with the view controller hierarchy, like adding another view controller's view as a subview without using the iOS 5 containment methods or normal view controller presentation methods (presentViewController: and friends).

Comment: Agreed. If doing `pushViewController`, you shouldn't have this problem. But too many developers out there are doing `addSubview`...

Comment: thank you for you suggestion. However neither of them resolves my problem. :( I've removed all "removeObserver:self" calls and already using pushViewController to present view controller B from A.

Comment: You say that B's viewDidUnload is correctly called. Does the stack trace for that call include the memory warning notification? I think it usually does. Perhaps that would give you some clue as to whether your view controller is, in fact, receiving that notification. (Could you have a typo in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`?)

Comment: @JesseRusak thank you for your advices. =) I'm very new to iOS platform and Xcode environment, though. I'll try to figure out doing what you suggested and add comments about it.